# Derivatives of probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Simple question: Do the Gradient and the Laplacian of a continuous probability density have a special name? They appear in a problem I am working on, and I want to search the literature for texts that might help. I am interested in how they are related for the joint and marginal density.

Comment: Why would they have a name???

Comment: Good question. I have changed the wording.

Comment: No they don't have a special name